# Produce two distinct topologies of R such that the first is strictly finer than the second but the two are homeomorphic to each other.

Tags: general-topology

Need to prove that they are homeomorphic to each other. 
So if T_1 and T_2 are topologies on set X with T_1 contained in T_2, every element of T_1 will be in T_2 and T_2 is the "finer" (stronger and larger) topology. So to them be homeomorphic is T_1 going to have to be a hole in T_2?

Comment: If two topology are homeomorphic, the topology should be the same.

Comment: What do you mean by a hole? There are a couple nice constructions of this, but they tend not to be particularly "normal" topologies.

Comment: Well if T1 is an open set settled in T2 can we assume they are homeomorphic because T1 has the same elements as T2? Therefore a bijection and with f: X->Y continuous and f^(-1): Y->X continuous they are homeomorphic and T2 is strictly finer than T1?

Comment: This question is an exercise in a well-known textbook. I wish people would stop posting questions from textbooks on sites like this. It makes it annoyingly difficult to create homework for my students, knowing that they can simply google the exact statement of the question and immediately find an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate $T_1$ by the intervals $(-2n,2n)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. (The topology is generated by taking all unions and finite intersections of these sets - which really doesn't add anything except the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ through an infinite union. And this also includes $(0,0)$ which means $\{\emptyset\}$.)

Generate $T_2$ by the intervals $(-n,n)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I believe these topologies meets your needs. The homeomorphism is just $x\mapsto2x$.

Comment: An even more crude example: Topologies where, along with all of $\mathbb{R}$, the open sets are either collections of even integers or collections of integers. You could even require these integers all be nonnegative. Multiplication by $2$ works again as the homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $$\mathscr{B}_1=\{[2n,2n+2):n\in\Bbb Z\}$$ and $$\mathscr{B}_2=\{[n,n+1):n\in\Bbb Z\}\;,$$

and take these as bases for $T_1$ and $T_2$, respectively.