# Homeomorphic topologies on a set.

Tags: general-topology

Show that there exists a set $X$, and two topologies $\tau$, and $\tau′$ on $X$, such that $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$, but $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau′)$ are homeomorphic.

I think $X$ must be a infinite set, but I  still don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/551156/1107685 gives an example

Comment: You are correct that it must be infinite. If the set is finite, then the topology is also finite, so $\tau'$ being strictly finer than $\tau$ means $\tau'$ has strictly more open sets, so they can't be homeomorphic.